# Parallel Download with the same Intent Service

Tags: android

I have one Intent Service that process a download and unzip of some file.
Now I'm trying to use this same Intent Service to download simultaneous files, but when I try to initiate the second download it just enqueue the new download, how can I not enqueue my downloads?

```
Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloadAndUnzipService.class);

service.putExtra("post", false);
service.putExtra("url", htmlUrlDownload);
service.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
service.putExtra("destinationPath", destinationPath);
service.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
service.putExtra("typeDownload", Constants.HTML);
service.putExtra("metaDado", downloadContent.getMetaDado());
service.putExtra("isResuming", false);

getActivity().startService(service);
```

I didn't put DownloadAndUnzipService code because it's too long and I think it won't help, but if is helpful I can update it.

Comment: If you want to use the same object of DownloadAndUnzipService you have to handle it there, so the code of it would help. Maybe you can shorten it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IntentService` is specifically designed to queue up multiple calls to it, and run them one at a time.

i.e. It is working 100% correctly, but unfortunately your design is wrong.

You should look into somthing like a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that will enable you to run multiple `Runnables` simultaneously from a thread pool. [Check out the Android docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

You will also see some good sample code. Otherwise, I know Mark Murphy's ebooks have some great code for parallel downloading.

I'm not sure if you need to put that into an actual `Service` or if you can keep it in one of your `Activities` - that depends on your exact aims.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to continue using a ResultReceiver to communicate a standard Thread with my activity ?

Answer (score 2):

if DownloadAndUnzipService is a subclass of IntentService that is the expected behavior.

rea a little bit more at: [Extends an Intent Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService)

If you wanna a parallel download, you would need to [extend from Service class](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) and manage the background thread by your self